# Why does getResourceAsStream() return null when File does not exist before start of Test method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, assertj

Before flagging this as a duplicate please read the question!

I have a JUnit Test which tests a method that writes its result in a `file`. To check the result I want to read that result file and check its content.

The problem is that when the result file does not already exist before the start of the test, the method `getResourceAsStream()` returns `null`.

My code for the Test is something like this:

```
@Inject
private ObjectToTest obj

@Test
public void testMethod() throws Exception {
    // Do some setup (inject mocks, set properties of obj, ...)

    obj.method(); // <-- Creates result.txt
    Mockito.verify(obj).method();

    // Thread.sleep(1000); <-- I have tried to use this to wait some time for the result, but it did not work

    // This part is null on the first run of the test
    // When I run the test the second time, the file does already exist and it returns the right InputStream for the File
    InputStream resultInp = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test-out/result.txt");

    String resultStr = IOUtils.toString(resultInp, "UTF-8");

    assertThat(resultStr).isNotNull();
    assertThat(resultStr.split("\n")).hasSize(5);
}
```

Is there any explanation to why this happens or must it have to do something with another part of the code?

I have not found anything regarding this issue on StackOverflow, but if I am wrong please guide me to the right post.

Comment: What do you expect as output, if there are no file?

Comment: What do you mean? There is a file. I gets created in the `obj.method()` method, I can see it in the explorer and when the test runs a second time it also recognizes the file. @DDovzhenko

Comment: It wasn't obvious from the first sight, that file is created in `obj.method()`

Comment: Sorry I will edit the question to make it more clear! @DDovzhenko

Comment: Could you try to call `ResourceBundle.clearCache();` before getting resource? It can be ClassLoader caches all available resources.

Comment: @DDovzhenko - I don't think that will help.  The OP is not using a ResourceBundle, and the stuff that is being cached is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `getResourceAsStream()` method returns a stream for a resource on the classpath, using directory / index information that is cached by the classloader.  If you add a resource to some directory tree or archive on the classpath after the classpath has been cached, the classloader is likely to not "see" it<sup>1</sup>.

That is most likely is what has happened in your test code.

A Java application should not be trying to treat classloader resources like a general purpose file system.  Instead, use `File` or `Path` to denote files, and `FileInputStream` or similar to open them.

---

<sup>1 - The actual behavior does not appear to be specified in the javadocs for `ClassLoader`, etcetera.  My description is based on the observed / reported behavior of some Java implementations.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the information. Will use `FileInputStream` for this purpose then!